# correlation analysis for big data set

Tags: r, correlation

I am doing a pairwise correlation for 20,000 genes. I used the **rcorr** function in **Hmisc** package. Then, I extracted the pvalues and correlation coefficient values from the result object. I applied FDR correction for the pvalues and did not get a significant gene below the 0.05 cutoff. However, almost 80 % of the genes have strong correlation coefficients(>= 0.9).
The structure of my data and the code I used are simulated below. If my data and code are correct, I wonder why I did not get a single correlated gene after FDR correction, while most genes show a strong correlation?

```
set.seed(1)
    A <- data.frame(rnorm(100), 
                    rnorm(100),
                    rnorm(100), 
                    rnorm(100),
                    rnorm(100))
    row.names(A) <- paste0("G_", 1:100)
    colnames(A) <- paste0("S_", 1:5)
    
    set.seed(42)  
    B <- data.frame(rnorm(100), 
                    rnorm(100),
                    rnorm(100), 
                    rnorm(100),
                    rnorm(100))
    row.names(B) <- paste0("I_", 1:100)
    colnames(B) <- paste0("S_", 1:5)
    
    library(dplyr)
    library(Hmisc)
    library(reshape2)
## Bind the rows
    all <-bind_rows(A, B)
    ## Correlation as transposed matrix 
    result <- rcorr(as.matrix(t(all))) 
    hist(result$P,br=100)
    ath.p <- round(result$P,3)
## Extract the top right block of the matrix
    ath.pp <- ath.p[1:100, 101:200]
    cor <- melt(as.matrix(ath.pp))
    p.adj <- p.adjust(cor$value, method = "BH")
    ath.data <- cbind(cor,p.adj)
    at <- ath.data %>% filter(value >=0.05)
 
## Correlation coff
    ath.r <- round(result$r,3)
## Extract the top right block of the matrix
   ath.rr <- ath.r[1:100, 101:200]
   cor.r <- melt(as.matrix(ath.rr))
```

Comment: I tried to address the issue in the post below. Quite honestly... the above code you have, will give you a all null hypothesis.. so you need to provide context about your data

Answer (score 1):

This part of the code is quite problematic:

```
ath.p <- round(result$P,3)
```

If you have a p-value < 0.001 it gets rounded to zero.. which would be grossly wrong.

```
round(1e-04,3)
[1] 0
```

It should not affect your result that there's no significance. However, looking at the code, note that you are doing a correlation between matrices and not a pairwise comparison.

What exactly are these two matrices and why would you expect a correlation between the genes from two different group of samples? You need to provide this context in your question!!!!!

Below I can use an example dataset, and the pairwise correlation within a sample will show p.values that pass the adjustment. The correlation between samples, because they are not related in any sense, should show much much lesser:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(multtest)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
data(golub)

mat = golub
rownames(mat) = paste0("G",1:nrow(mat))
#split the samples up randomly
m1 = mat[,seq(1,ncol(mat),2)]
m2 = mat[,seq(2,ncol(mat),2)]

test = rcorr(t(rbind(m1,m2)))

n = nrow(m1)
```

If we look at the pairwise comparison within the sample, I am sure you get p-values that pass the FDR (i excluded the self correlation here):

```
results = melt(test$r[1:n,1:n],value.name ="pcc") %>% 
filter(Var1!=Var2)%>%  
left_join(melt(test$P[1:n,1:n],value.name ="p"),by=c("Var1","Var2"))
```

If you look at the histogram of p values, you see an enrichment of low p-values, indicating this will pass the FDR (as it deviates from an all null hypothesis). This plot is missing from your actual data:

```
hist(results$p,br=100)
```

[image]

```
table(p.adjust(results$p,"BH")<0.05)

  FALSE    TRUE 
9258610   46940
```

Now if we look at the correlation between the matrices:

```
results = melt(test$r[1:n,(n+1):(2*n)],value.name ="pcc") %>% 
left_join(melt(test$P[1:n,(n+1):(2*n)],value.name ="p"),by=c("Var1","Var2"))

head(results)
  Var1 Var2         pcc         p
1   G1   G1  0.28368867 0.2391968
2   G2   G1  0.11289293 0.6454033
3   G3   G1 -0.03138222 0.8985162
4   G4   G1 -0.11531721 0.6382801
5   G5   G1 -0.11807959 0.6302003
6   G6   G1 -0.10628946 0.6649551

hist(results$p,br=100)
```

[image]

You can appreciate that there are less enrichment in smaller p-values, and of course if you do FDR, you get less:

```
table(p.adjust(results$p,"BH")<0.05)

  FALSE    TRUE 
9308363     238
```

Comment: I am satisfied with your detailed explanations! Basically, I am doing this analysis to get an idea if genes of two tissues in the same patients(T2D) show correlation or not? Doing the same analysis for other patients (patients with kidney diseases or hypertension ) and compare correlated genes in a network graph. Therefore, the gene correlation exists in the two tissues of the three different disease state can be compared. I really would like to get some advice if this is the wrong way to go. Thank you!

Comment: Ok yes if they are the same patients, different tissues, it make sense. The issue is do you have enough samples to make this correlation

Comment: Yes, that is the issue! However, how many samples it should be to satisfy the assumption? I have 6-10 samples.   Thanks!

Comment: might be too little considering you are testing 20000x20000. Suggest you try to narrow down to like 3000 genes. for one you can eliminate genes that are expressed in 1 tissue and not the other

Comment: If I may ask one more time here,  how you advise me to extract those 238 significant genes from the matrix test$r[1:n,(n+1):(2*n)] for heatmap and network plot?. Some lines of codes would be pretty much helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @DowithR, i am afraid that's a different question altogether. You can try posting it as another question,using the example I have. Have I answered your question above?

Comment: If I could able to extract those 238 significant genes from the matrix test$r[1:n,(n+1):(2*n)], then the heatmap and other staff I can do it. Thanks!

Comment: try ```sig = droplevels(results[p.adjust(results$p,"BH")<0.05,]) ; results %>% filter(Var1 %in% sig$Var1 & Var2 %in% sig$Var2) %>% recast(Var1 ~ Var2,data=.,measure.var="pcc")```

Comment: Thank you so much!